# How does the maximum kinetic energy of an ejected electron affect what happen to it after being ejected?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

So I just learned: $$K_{max} = hf - \phi$$($\phi$ for ionization energy)

I wonder what will happen if $K_max$ is zero. Will it be attracted back to the ionized atom it has come from since it doesn't have any energy to move away from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ejected Electrons with 0 KE?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45732/)

Comment: @JohnRennie, so I was correct in saying that if the electron has too little energy, or no energy at all, it will get pulled back into the atom? But how much is too little?